# BadMethodCallException: Trying to list all partners with the categories laravel

Tags: laravel, many-to-many

I'm experiencing the following:
Goal: I would like to list all partners and the categories they belong to. Basically, it's a many to many relationship.

Below is the code:
**Partner Categories Table Migration**

```
 public function up()
  {
    Schema::create('partcats', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('partcatnameP')->unique();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
  }
```

**Partners Table Migration**

```
    public function up()
   {
    Schema::create('partners', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('partnername');

        $table->string('regnumber')->unique();

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('activestatus_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('activestatus_id')->references('id')->on('activestatuses');

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
  }
```

**Partner_Category Migration**

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('partner_partcat', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('partner_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('partner_id')->references('id')->on('partners')->onDelete('cascade');



$table->unsignedBigInteger('partcat_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('partcat_id')->references('id')->on('partcats')->onDelete('cascade');


        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Models are as shown below:

**Partcat Model**

```
public function partners()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Partcat','partner_partcat');
}
```

**Partner Model**

```
 public function partcats()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Partcat','partner_partcat');
}
```

and the Partners Controller is as shown below:

```
    public function index()
{
    //
    $partners = Partner::all()->partcats();

  // dd(Partner::all()->partcats());

    return view('partners.index',['partners'=>$partners]);

}
```

This is where I'm trying to retrieve the list of partners and its related categories.  However, I get a BadMethod call error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following method

```
$partners = Partner::with('partcats')->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: How would I go about displaying this the partcats on blade?

Comment: ```@foreach($partners->partcats as $partcat)  {{ $partcat }} @endforeach```

Answer (score 0):

A many to many pivot table typically has the id for both tables it is relating.

The Partner_Category migration you have posted only seems to contain a partner_id. You may need to add in the category_id.

```
   public function up()
{
    Schema::create('partner_partcat', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('partner_id')->unsigned();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('partcat_id')->unsigned();

        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('partner_id')->references('id')->on('partners')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('partcat_id')->references('id')->on('partcats')->onDelete('cascade');
      });
}
```

Comment: Excellent. I would expect the advice Aniket gave to resolve things once this is updated and the migration re-run. Are you still seeing the error?

Comment: James Clark Developer, Yes, its a great answer. Now just stuck with displaying the list of partner categories on blade.